# SUM all data in the same date and group data in certain range

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
df = {
'Date': ['1-8','1-8','1-8','2-8','2-8','2-8'],
'Value1': [9,12,7,8,15,16],
'Value2': [1,3,2,4,2,3]}
```

I want to sum Value2 in 2 groups, based on Value1(1-10,11-20) and date
and create a new dataframe
with 3 columns
Date,1-10,11-20.

I also want the range be extendable
like 1-10,11-20,21-30.....>100
so i am thinking of something like

```
for i in range(0, 100, 10)
```

but no idea how to put the date condition

so that the final result is like:

```
new_df = {
'Date': ['1-8','2-8'],
'1-10': [3,4],
'11-12':[3,5]}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, I had to post my answer again because it was deleted. I'd appreciate accepting it (again)